# How can I add a scroll/see more feature to my 'Latest Products' on the WooCommerce platform?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a 'Latest Products' loop by inserting the following code into my 'index.php' file:

```
<section id="recent">
    <h1>Recently Added</h1>
    <ul class="row-fluid">
    <?php
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'stock' => 1, 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'orderby' =>'date','order' => 'DESC' );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; 
    ?>
        <li class="span3">    
            <a id="id-<?php the_id(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" width="65px" height="115px" />'; ?>
                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <span class="price">
                <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>
                </span>
            </a>
                <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product ); ?>

        </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </ul>
</section>
```

I now wish to be able to apply an arrow on the left and right of this row, where upon selecting the arrow, it will scroll through the images.

I am aware of the following codes:

```
<?php previous_post_link(); ?>
<?php next_post_link(); ?>
```

However, upon selection of their links, the user is taken to its dedicated page rather than being able to 'scroll' through the products.

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for a carousel? There are a lot of jQuery plugins, i have used [this](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/) one.

If you choose this solution, you should get the script, put it in your theme, add it, preferably in functions.php (more info [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)) and then add the carousel itself.

```
$('.row-fluid').owlCarousel({})
```

But insteal of all this maybe using a plugin like "WooCommerce Product Slider" or similar will be better. It provides shorcode and widget implementation which should work with most themes and can be used directly in the control panel withouth coding. One more note - if you still prefer to use your own code - maybe it'll be better to put it in a template file instead in index.php